# Put previos data in table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I've table with with 3 column with the following name

```
name  <----input field - first column
user   <----CheckBox -second column
address<----CheckBoxv-third column
```

I've in the table in-line create and if user click on edit for specific row and 
change the name /user/address and instead of save do cancel I want to restore the previos data,I was able to do this for the input property but not sure how to do it for the checkBoxes,any idea how?

This is how I restore the data for the name property

```
      var $firstCell = $row.find("td:first"),
      checkBox = $row.find("input[type=checkbox]"),

....

    $firstCell.text(previousData.name);
```

In the previosData I store all the data when the user just click on edit

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is something like this:

```
var $checkboxUser = $row.find('input[name=user]'),
    $checkboxAddress = $row.find('input[name=address]');

previousData.statusUserCheckbox = $checkboxUser.prop('checked');
previousData.statusAddressCheckbox = $checkboxAddress.prop('checked');

// ...

$checkboxUser.prop('checked', previousData.statusUserCheckbox);
$checkboxAddress.prop('checked', previousData.statusAddressCheckbox);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/